# I have a Mach One BMX, help me decipher its serial number

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

I have an all original (as purchased) GT Mach One, but I can not find typical info a serial number and other stampings usually provide. Can any of you steer me in the right direction to help decipher what my serial numbers say about my bicycle? I’ve listed them below so they’re easy to see and copy.

I bought it in 2001, I believe.  It was new, and of that year range.

The numbers are on the bottom bracket, each on one opposite sides as they appear below:

> SICT00122
>
> GE 2024

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what do you actually want to know about this bike?

Comment: Curious it’s actual age and origin of MFG , any other info the serial provides that someone would want if looking to purchase.

Comment: Try and figure out why your photo is not loading.  The max permitted size is 2 Megabytes.  Or post it on Imgur.com and add the link, and someone else can sort out getting the image in-line.

Comment: I don't understand why this would be "unclear what you are asking for". These questions are difficult to answer, but against all odds this even was answered.

Comment: Thank you ojs, I was almost able to figure it out thru google and other links but just merely escaped me and this is one place google led me.. simple question about serial numbers, what’s so un clear?!?!?

Comment: You really should read some of the similar old questions before asking new one, the same discussion has been done over and over. Usually there's no way to extract any information from serial, you just got lucky

Comment: @Millennialmach1 basically serial numbers on a bike are for stock control during manufacturing and sales, they prove a warranty is for this particular bike.  Generally going backward from the serial number to a maker is impossible, because there is no central database like there is for motor vehicle VINs.  Fortunately the GT seems to be a well-documented and popular brand so their info has been reverse engineered to some extent.  Regardless, your bike is your bike, and like a puppy from a dog pound is still your dog.  Provenance of pedigree is nice, but not needed to ride your bike.

Comment: @ojs I looked for approximately two hours and it was like a big circle that kept leading me to a really good reference rabke someone made for tons of makes and models but in the GT part it simply lacked anything resembling what I have, so why not ask? I understand it’s likely redundant but clearly I’ve got something unique in an unsavory way and I just want to get to the bottom of exactly what it is. Those who’ve simply helped out, I’m extremely grateful. Thanks guys. And gals if you’re out there.

Comment: https://m.imgur.com/gallery/pVPVLZ6  hopefully that works but it’s hardly legible from what I saw but I have listed off those engravings/ stamps in OP and working on getting the bike pic up

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/F4KypIl.jpg

Comment: I have to sat that's a nice bike.  The distinctive features are the head tube gusset (strengthening plate between top and downtube just aft of the headtube), the general ratios of the frame angles, and perhaps the stem with its unusual forward facing bolts.   The cranks also look cottered but with a bolt at the opposite side from the crank arm.   I do note it has a V brake on the back wheel, which may be a later fitment.  I'm not much up on BMXs.  The tyres look inordinately black - were they coloured with tyre black or just brand-new and never ridden ?

Comment: Thanks Criggie, I’ve always liked the GT bmx over others and that’s why I got it (my2nd) and haven’t let go of it. You’re correct it is a later year. Someone suggested the T means 20th letter alphabet = 20 years after 1980, meaning 2000. Made sense, since I got it in 01 or 02 latest. Also beyond the lighting yes the tyres are black from being cleaned , they and everything else aside the inner tubes and the grips are all original and so appx 18 urs old. The pad set I have is red and black also but slight faded need new.

Answer (score 4):

Mach One seems to be a model of BMX made by GT.

Their numbering system seems to be

- S - Company that made the frame.  K would mean Kinesis, but Robinson, Dyno, Powerlite and Auburn also made GT frames.   Not sure what company is represented by which letters.
- I - Site/location that made the frame.  This is an optional field.
- C - Third letter of alphabet, so it was made in March
- T - 20th letter of the alphabet, so it's year is 1980 +20 == 2000.

Your bike was made in March 2000, and probably took a few months to arrive at the retailer whence you bought it.

From https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/info/122/ and others.

You can see 31 "Mach One" BMXs in this search
https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/search?q=mach&year-start=2000&year-end=2001

---

Now the bad news - a Mach One has "M1" stamped on the BB by the serial number.   Yours doesn't, so it might not be what you think it is.

---

You can try registering your GT bike at https://www.gtbicycles.com/can_en/bike-registration  by entering the serial and your email address.   See what they can tell you about it.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what the GE 2024 could represent, nor what the individual letters might stand for.   My google-fu is weak today.

Comment: Thanks for all who understood my simple questions and added what they could to help. The knowledge provided is great and will help me figure it out. It’s possible they simply took an interceptor frame and Mach one decals and sold to me. It was a bike shop in Mesa Arizona amd I believe it’s still operating. I in fact know I still have the receipt to this bike somewhere but I have receipts for almost everything and it’s basixally a bill if sale from memory.. nothing specific. Which also means shady. Thanks again I’ll keep plugging away.

Comment: @Millennialmach1 try registering your serial number and email address with GT at that link.  It might work.